# CIR Process-Variance reduction

Tags: r, references, markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, methodology

I'm trying to evaluate a path dependent function, $f(r_t)$, on a [Cox-Ingersoll-Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model) process:

$$dr_t = \theta (\mu - r_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt r_t dW_t$$

by Monte Carlo simulation.

Could anyone suggest and explain any effective variance reduction techniques that could be used on this process?  E.g. importance sampling, stratified sampling etc.

---

*Original Question*:

Is anybody aware of advanced variance reduction techniques (i.e. importance sampling or stratified sampling) for the simulation of [Cox-Ingersoll-Ross process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIR_process)? Ideally I would like to see a concrete implementation if available...

Regards

Comment: Asking for a concrete implementation may be asking a bit much, but other than that, it's hard to see why this question currently has a vote to close as *not constructive*.

Comment: Sorry, should have commented.  I flagged the question because it is very old and there is no progress.  "not constructive" seemed the best fit.  The question is very open ended and to seems to answer itself (Importance sampling, stratified sampling).  It doesn't give any indication as to what has already been tried nor what the problems with these methods are.  Perhaps if the question can be reworked to say "can someone explain importance sampling for CIR" or whatever the problem actually is.  At the moment this seems unanswerable.

Comment: @cardinal An edit to rescue the question would of course be preferred, but in this case I just couldn't see how to do it without making up the question.  If someone or the OP can work this into a good question, that would be great.

Comment: Come on people, you complained that this shouldn't be closed, but neither an answer, edit or even a comment to nudge us towards resolution.  I'll try clean the question myself best I can...